# Unable to resume Activity when retrieving images from SD card

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, android-cursor

My Activity contains this code to get all images on the SD card:

```
String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.Media._ID,
                       MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA,
                       MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA};  
Cursor cursor = managedQuery(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                             projection, null, null,
                             MediaStore.Images.Media._ID); 
int count = cursor.getCount();
int image_path_index = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
int i;
for(i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    cursor.moveToPosition(i);
    String p = cursor.getString(image_path_index);
    fd.addToPhonePhoto(p);
}
cursor.close();
```

The occurred while the Activity was resuming:

> 03-14 14:06:48.380: E/AndroidRuntime(20793): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {}: android.database.StaleDataException: Attempted to access a cursor after it has been closed.

It only occurs on Android 4.0. If on Android 2.x or 3.x, it works normally. But if I change the system setting which selects the "don't keep Activities" option in "Developer options".
The error does not show.

I want to modify my code to avoid this error without changing the system setting. How should I do it?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I think this is because of the `managedQuery` call + you closing the cursor. From the docs of the [`managedQuery()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#managedQuery%28android.net.Uri,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String%29) method:

> Warning: Do not call close() on a cursor obtained using this method,
>   because the activity will do that for you at the appropriate time.
>   However, if you call stopManagingCursor(Cursor) on a cursor from a
>   managed query, the system will not automatically close the cursor and,
>   in that case, you must call close().

Leave the cursor for the Android system to manage and don't call `cursor.close();`.

**`Note:`** The `managedQuery` method is deprecated and **it should be avoided**, implement [**`CursorLoaders`**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/CursorLoader.html) instead. More info about `CursorLoaders` can be found at [`developer.android.com`](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html).

Comment: Your answer are right. But another activity of mine has the same error. The code like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9426170/why-the-cusor-null . If did not call cursor.close(), the cousor will get null while run several loop. How to avoid it?

Comment: @brian Maybe the problems from your other question are because of the size of the operations you do. You do a full query of the MediaStore.Images.Media` for two columns, and then make several hundreds(or even over 1000) `managedQuery` to get the thumbnails(also if you want the thumbnail shouldn't you query the `MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails` contentprovider?). Also you say that the cursor is sometimes null, but wouldn't calling close on the cursor throw a `NullPointerException`?

Comment: For example, I have 2000 photo. The for loop from 1 to 1000 works but more then 1000 will get null. If use NullPointerException may cause several photo did not be open.

Comment: @brian I don't know why that happens. Maybe you could try a new approach and avoid the issue.

Comment: OK, reduce the cursor call seems the only method. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

remove `cursor.close();`  in your code
it work fine definitely

Answer (score 1):

Function, managedQuery() is deprecated.

Please use getContentResolver().query().

The parameters is the same.